# collectd failing to write to influxDB "Failed to dispatch rabbitmq_default. Exception Dataset publish_out_details not found"

Tags: python, rabbitmq, influxdb, collectd

I have installed collectd-rabbitmq plugin in collectd.config to fetch the RabbitMQ queue_value data by accessing RabbitMQ admin page (management plugin) via HTTP and it worked, but for security i have installed ssl for that RabbitMQ admin page and now colletd is failing to write the queue data to InfluxDB with this error

> "**Failed to dispatch
>   rabbitmq_default.exchanges.queue-name.publish_out_details.sample.
>   Exception Dataset publish_out_details not found**".

I am seeing this error log in collectd log file which means collectd is talking to RabbitMQ admin page(since it has the queue name in its log), but i cannot see this data (queues_values) populated in InfluxDB.

This collectd is able to write cpu_usage, disk_space, memory_utilization metrics to InfluxDB but just failing to write the Queue data.
Python plugin used:

```
<Plugin python>
  LogTraces true
  Interactive false
  Import "collectd_rabbitmq.collectd_plugin"
  <Module "collectd_rabbitmq.collectd_plugin">
    Username "user_name"
    Password "password"
    Realm "RabbitMQ Management"
    Host "hostname.com"
    Port "443"
    Scheme "https"
  </Module>
</Plugin>
```

InfluxDB version using 1.2.1
Collectd Version: 5.8.0

Is there something to do with the python plugin or typesDB, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

It probably has something to do with the typesDB configuration, and I ran into the same issues. CollectD seems to be picky regarding the configuration of the types. If you just get the types from here (https://github.com/NYTimes/collectd-rabbitmq/blob/master/config/types.db.custom), save it to `/usr/share/collectd/rabbitmq.types.db` and update your `collectd.conf` to include this, then it should work:

`TypesDB "/usr/share/collectd/rabbitmq.types.db"
TypesDB "/usr/share/collectd/types.db"`

If you want the information to appear in influxDB you should also add these types to the `types.db` file used by InfluxDB.